Dualshock 4 USB Wireless Adaptor produces constant right stick upward signal, even with no Controller connected
I have been using the official Playstation DualShock 4 USB Wireless Adaptor, since I bought it back in 2020. Today I realised that its right stick is constantly drifting upwards, this however is not a problem with my PS4 Controller (which is brand new, bought 1 month ago) but instead is a bug from the stick itself.
I have the USB Adaptor connected to my Windows 10 PC, with no controller connected to it, and I am getting a constant Up singal for the right/second stick, as is being detected here by Joytokey.

This signal is so strong, that I am unable to combat it even by pressing the right stick on a connected controller all the way down. In that case the signal will still go up and no down signal will be detected. The signal is also so strong that it is still detected, even if I set Joytokey's Input Threshold for that stick to 100%

Using the Windows USB-Controller calibration tool indicates no problems though, I can move all 4 values: Z-Axis, aswell as X-,Y- and Z-Rotation up and down without issue. The X and Y Rotation both are at 0% default value, while both Z values are at 49-50%, I am not sure if that is normal or an indication of the buggy behavior,

I have tried doing the reset to default here, with no effect and have also tried the manual calibration, the latter of which I am unable to complete, as it requires pressing the 2 trigger buttons, to move their respective axis, which Windows then for some reason also interprets as pressing a button to progress the menu, leaving me unable to actually calibrate the controller. Again, I am unsure if this is normal or part of the bug.
While playing FF7 on Steam as an example and setting the right stick to moving up, down, left and right on the controller with JoytoKey. I am typically unable to move up or down with the right stick, while left and right work without issue, though I have also experienced being stuck constantly walking up.
While playing Don't Starve Together (without JoyTokey, using the native Steam controller settings) I am experiencing a constant drift to the left for the selection coursor when opening the Items Menu at the bottom of the screen, when I try to move it to the right with the left stick. I am unable to move it with the right stick. This is really confusing to me, because when using an Xbox 360 controller, I can only move this menu with the left and right of either stick, but not with up, which is the direction the PS4 Adapter is drifting in. Note that if I don't disconnect the PS4 Adapter before using the Xbox Controller with Don't Starve together, I get the PS4's drift in this menu aswell, but can combat it by pressing the right stick all the way to the right on the Xbox Controller.
What can I possible do to fix this issue (other than buying a new wireless adapter)? I was unable to find any driver updates for the stick, and of course changing the USB Port does not solve the problem, there is also no difference between connecting it to a USB 2.0 or 3.0 port and the issue is also consistent on another PC, so the problem lies almost certainly with the stick.

Possible stick-drift on your controller. Otherwise, get new Wireless Adaptor. Or have someone at a techshop examine it for you. And maybe they can fix it for you (I'd still recommend you get a new adaptor though).
